What is an example of a DAG that is *not* an arborescence?
From the Wikipedia article on "arborescence":

An arborescence is a directed graph where there exists a vertex r (called the root) such that, for any other vertex v, there is exactly one directed walk from r to v (noting that the root r is unique).
(...)
Every arborescence is a directed acyclic graph (DAG), but not every DAG is an arborescence.

I think I figured this one out, but I would like to get confirmation. I highlighted the part above in italics that I deem the distinguishing property between the two concepts.
My example where DAG is not an arborescence, because, for example, e can be reached via multiple paths from a:

My example that is both a DAG and an arborescence, because it is clearly a DAG and each vertex has a single path from the root ("source"?):


For context, I'm trying to understand adjacency lists / hierarchical relations in relation with relational databases.

While you got the spirit of it right, the definition of arborescence asks for existence of a root. In your example of a DAG that is not an arborescence, all you showed is that $a$ is not a root of an arborescence. There could well be another root with respect to which that graph is an arborescence. Can you see that there is no vertex that can be a possible root?

@Pranay I totally missed that, thank you! "Can you see that there is no vertex that can be a possible root?" Yes, but doesn't this prove that even though that graph is a DAG, it is not an arborescence? (Sorry, never got to proofs, and I'm just realizing how careful I have to be with my statements - and assumptions.)

It is indeed a DAG but not an arborescence. My point was only that your proof was incomplete.

@Pranay Ah, got it - and thanks for the clarification!

Did you mean to link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)?

@MishaLavrov Yes... Fixed it and thank you for catching it!:)

The examples are both correct, but there is a different way that a DAG can fail to be an arborescence. Consider the following directed graph: $$x \to y \gets z$$
This is a DAG, but not an arborescence, because no matter which vertex you pick as the root, it will not be able to reach all the others. From $x$, we cannot reach $z$, from $z$, we cannot reach $x$, and from $y$, we cannot reach $x$ or $z$.
There are two useful ways to characterize arborescences:

You can start with the undirected notion of a tree, pick a root $r$, and then orient all edges in the direction away from $r$. This always results in an arborescence, and all arborescences can be obtained in this way.
The root must have indegree $0$, and every other vertex must have indegree $1$. This does not characterize arborescences by itself, but it does if we add either the condition that the digraph is weakly connected (that we cannot separate it into two pieces with no arcs between them in either direction), or the condition that the digraph has no cycles.

From both of these properties, it follows that an arborescence with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ arcs (though, as my starting example shows, this is not sufficient).

Doesn’t the following fully characterize when a DAG is arborescence? A DAG is an arborescence if and only if it has only one source and the underlying undirected graph is connected and acyclic.

@Pranay Yes, that's correct. I think it is substantially saying the same thing as point 1 in my answer.
